# Parent container div does not adjust width when it contains an wide overflown div child

Tags: html, css

See the following (very simple) page markup:

```html
<div style="border: 3px dotted lightpink;">
  <div style="border: 3px dotted lightblue;">
    Normal div
  </div>
  <div style="width: 2500px; height: 200px; border: 3px dotted lightgray;">
    Overflow div
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla. Gravida neque convallis a cras semper auctor. Scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Odio euismod lacinia at quis. Est sit amet facilisis magna. Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id. Magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean.
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does the outermost container (with pink border) not grow horizontally to enclose the innermost overflown container (grey border). It does grow vertically to fit, I would expect it should also grow horizontally.

Comment: because it's block element so by default 100% of **parent** width (nothing about content) .. use inline-block

Comment: Block elements just behave that way. You’d probably have to delve quite deep into the specification to find the place where this is actually written down, but the web evolved as a medium that mainly extends along the Y axis. Make the outer div `display:inline-block`, and maybe add a `min-width: 100%` if you need it to extend over the full width if all content should be less wide.

Comment: add overflow:auto to parent div

Answer (score 0):

Just use display: inline-block in pink container:

```
<div style="border: 3px dotted lightpink;display:inline-block">
<div style="border: 3px dotted lightblue;">
    Normal div
</div>
<div style="width: 2500px; height: 200px; border: 3px dotted lightgray;">
    Overflow div
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla. Gravida neque convallis a cras semper auctor. Scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Odio euismod lacinia at quis. Est sit amet facilisis magna. Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id. Magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stefano Pascazi... I'm more interested in the why rather in how to fix it... Temani Afif and misorude provided insight of why in the comments to the question above